# Breezingforms change encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, breezingforms

I am trying to use a custom script I wrote which collects form data in submit pieces and emails it. The script runs great when the data entered is English. However for Hebrew I need the data to be encoded in ISO-8859-1. I believe it is being encoded now in utf-8. In a sample form (non breezy form) I was able to accomplish this by adding to the form tag as follows;

```
    <form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

and collecting the data from $_REQUEST array and that did the trick. I added the "accept charset" line to the breezyform but I could only collect the data using ff_submit ($_REQUEST comes up empty). Where can I change the forms encoding? I tried already using PHP to change the encoding of the string but that doesn't do it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't encode Hebrew in ISO-8859-1, since ISO-8859-1 only supports Western European languages written in the Latin script. You could transliterate it, or encode it in ISO-8859-8, but the simplest way to handle it is to return it in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was able to access the `$_REQUEST` array by adding `ff_nm_` to the field name, so instead of `$_REQUEST[myfield]` it's `$_REQUEST[ff_nm_myfield][0]` that will grab the element that you named in your breezingform "myfield"